# CURTIME adding and subtracting in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select users information from my database but I only want to retrieve those who logged in the last 3 hours

I tried the following :

```
SELECT * FROM user  WHERE last > CURTIME(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR ORDER BY last DESC
```

But it is not working. I guess I put the INTERVAL function in the wrong place. but I tried many approaches and it is still not working.

How can you fix it? is there a better way than using the CURTIME() function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `NOW()`, not `CURTIME()`, because CURTIME is just the time as a string, without the date. So if it's 1am, someone who logged in yesterday at 11pm would not be included.

```
SELECT * FROM USER
WHERE last > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
ORDER BY last DESC
```

Comment: Exactly met the requirement. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SUBTIME( curtime( ) , '03:00:00' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM user  WHERE ADDDATE(last, INTERVAL 3 HOUR)>CURTIME() ORDER BY last DESC
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HOURS)>CURTIME() ORDER BY last DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: fixed it by removing the `S` from `HOURS` but it is not giving me any result. even though, it should !

Comment: @shnisaka Sorry - I think it should be HOUR, not HOURS - Have you had any users in the last 3 hours?

Comment: yes ! three users 

and `last` is stored in this format : `2012-09-01 23:02:14`